# Cypress jQuery selector bar:contains('foo') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, selector

I tryıng to use jQuery selectors but it doesn't work. I use Cypress so sometimes I need to use jQuery selectors to find elements by text or some unique generated numbers. (instead of cy.contains() i.e. sometimes I can need to brake recursions etc.)

Can anyone help me please?

[image]

I tried so many selectors, one of those selectors is:

```
$(tbody:has(tr.dx-row.dx-data-row.dx-row-lines.dx-row-focused.dx-cell-focus-disabled) tr td:contains(`10304`))
```

[image]

the queries that I showed normally work well. But that question that I asked doesn't work suspiciously. I thought about maybe the console doesn't support queries but when I use :has command console shows me without a problem then why :contains doesn't work? Why I can't select elements with text that I asked as a question?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You can see the bottom of the console but I will share it.

Comment: Don't post code as images, post it a text so it is easier to read for us

Answer (score 0):

I think your selectors are very complicated, try to simplify them by maybe just select the `<td>`, that contains that text like in my example below.

For demonstration purposes, i show just the cell text (`.text()`) - but it can be whatever you want.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const $table = $('table');
  
  console.log($table.find('td:contains(10304)').text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="dx-row dx-data-row dx-row-lines andsoon">
      <td class="dx-command-select">UNASSIGNED</td>
      <td class="dx-col-1">10304</td>
      <td class="dx-col-2">YAYDIN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, my selectors are auto-generating by the DevExtreme React application development tool. And I think my problem causes by Virtual Dom. I  just wanted to mention it maybe bring new ideas about the problem to you. Now I am going to try your advice thank you!

Comment: .ready() gives the error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ready'). :(

Comment: I guess you ou can skip the whole `$(document).ready(() => {...}` part, it might be autogenerated by your framework

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but got an error too=> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'find'). I think while elements are in Virtual DOM find() cannot find them as like in static DOM elements.